# How to split Dictionary file to multiple data frames in Python

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, yfinance

Is there any possible way to split the each data frame and name as key of corresponding dict?

Like `AAIT` is one DataFrame and `AAL` is one DataFrame, etc

Scraping method

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf

start = pd.to_datetime('01/01/2015').date()
end = pd.to_datetime('today').date()

url="https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/nasdaq-listings/nasdaq-listed_csv/data/7665719fb51081ba0bd834fde71ce822/nasdaq-listed_csv.csv"
s = requests.get(url).content
companies = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))


Symbols = companies['Symbol'].tolist()


# create empty dataframe
stock_final = pd.DataFrame()
# iterate over each symbol
for i in Symbols[0:11]:  
    
    # print the symbol which is being downloaded
    print( str(Symbols.index(i)) + str(' : ') + i, sep=',', end=',', flush=True)  
    
    try:
        # download the stock price 
        stock = []
        stock = yf.download(i,start=start, end=end, progress=False)
        
        # append the individual stock prices 
        if len(stock) == 0:
            None
        else:
            stock['Name']=i
            stock_final = stock_final.append(stock,sort=False)
    except Exception:
        None
```

I want each in separate data frame, for this combine all as `dict` format.

[image: Sample DatFame]

Is there any other method to get separate DataFrames?

Comment: Use a dictionary of dataframes with stock as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing your code slightly should give you what you need.

1. Change `stock_final` to a `dict` instead of a DataFrame:
2. In your `for` loop, you simply assign the stock data to the specific key

###### Code:

```
symbols = companies['Symbol'].tolist()
stock_final = dict()
for i, s in enumerate(symbols[0:11]):  
    print(f"{i}: {s}")
    try:
        # download the stock price 
        stock = yf.download(s, start=start, end=end, progress=False)
        # add stock data to the final dictionary
        if len(stock) > 0:
            stock_final[s] = stock
    
    except Exception:
        pass
```